# Dispatching Action to Update Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a posting UI which i'm building and trying to maintain using redux.

I currently have a slice which resembles:

```
const jobsearchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "jobsearchSlice",
  initialState: {
    isFetching: false,
    searchComplete: false,
    roles: [],
    error: false,
    finalSelection: false,
    selectedRole: "",
    selectedRole: [],
    selectedStyle: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    searchStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.searchComplete = false;
      state.finalSelection = false;
    },
    searchSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.roles = action.payload;
      state.searchComplete = true;
      // state.searchComplete = false;
    },
    searchFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
    searchComplete: (state, action, term) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.roles = action.payload;
      state.searchComplete = true;
      state.finalSelection = true;
      state.selectedRole = term;
    },
    searchClear: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
    },
    searchUpdateStyle: (state, action, option) => {
      state.selectedStyle = option;
    },
  },
});
```

All these functions work except, **searchUpdateStyle**. With this, I'm trying to update the selectedStyle element.

My component is as such, and I want to dispatch the selection to Redux:

```
                    {/* style! */}
                    {
                    page === 0 && 
                    <Dropdown>
                      <Dropdown_Button
                      onClick={e => 
                          setisActive(!isActive)}
                      >
                          {/* {selectedStyle || "Choose style"} */}
                          { selectedStyle.length>1 &&
                          <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="black" >{selectedStyle}</Typography>
                          || 
                          <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="black" >Select Style</Typography>
                          }
                          
                          <span>
                              <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>
                          </span>
                      </Dropdown_Button>
                      {isActive &&
                      <Dropdown_Content>

                          {styleSelection.map((option) => (
                              <Dropdown_Item 
                                  key={option}
                                  onClick={(e) => {
                                  setselectedStyle(option)
                                  setisActive(false)
                                  updateStyle(dispatch, option)
                              }}
                              >
                                <Typography variant="subtitle5" color="black" sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "white" } }}>{option}</Typography>
                              </Dropdown_Item>
                          ))}
                      </Dropdown_Content>
                    }
```

The function being used is this:

```
export const updateStyle = async (dispatch, option) => {
  dispatch(searchUpdateStyle(option));
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

searchUpdateStyle takes 3 arguments: (state, action, option)

you are only passing one, which will be considered as the fist argument, which is in your case "state"

Comment: Hi asma, this shouldn't result in the issue and if the property isn't used it should be fine correct? This wouldn't cause the issue

Comment: if its not used you need to pass something still, since you're using the 1st and the 3rd. try searchUpdateStyle(state, null, option), this way "action" takes null but since you don't use it its not a problem in this case